# @JoinTable with WHERE

Tags: java, hibernate

Trying to implement a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629668/one-to-many-mapping-with-many-possibilities) I'm wondering, is there any way to have a WHERE clause when using the @JoinTable annotation. If you look at the question (just skip to the table layout) I would join the two tables together with @JoinTable on the USER_ID and CHANNEL_ID but get only where one of the statuses are true.

Note that I can't just do a query as the field gives me the ability to add and remove objects as per the DAO interface this class is implementing. Putting a query in the getter will not allow me to do this. I also can't use a UserChannel object that represents the map like [JB Nizet said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629668/one-to-many-mapping-with-many-possibilities/6629795#6629795) for the same reason

Is it possible to have a WHERE clause in the @JoinTable annotation with hibernate?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `@WhereJoinTable(clause = "your_condition")`